# App to control iPad power status

Tags: ios, power-management

I would like to figure out if it's possible to create an app which, after launch, will switch to the background and will be basically a "timer" to control turning the device ON or OFF (or maybe just regaining control and be "in the user's face") when 30 minutes have elapsed.

I *do understand* that an app like this is not going to be approved ever. And I *would like to NOT jailbreak* my iPad. To give a bit more context -- I just want to limit the time children can use the iPad. I do have an iOS dev account, so I can sign the app, use a provisioning profile with my target device, and install it there.

Is it possible, and where should I be looking into this? Obviously it's not a part of iOS SDK.

Comment: I highly doubt you can do this without jailbreaking, since turning ON/OFF device is the OS's privilege. I might be wrong, though

Answer (score 1):

If you want you could make something with push notifications (for example, after 30 minutes on iPad you will see "it's time to leave iPad and eat breakfest"). You cant make app which will "open" after time. Everything in background is *very* limited by iOS — there are push notifications and they should be used for every event.
If you want to do it you must jailbreak your iPad.

Edit:

I have a great solution for you.
Make a Web application that connects to iCloud and remote lock iPad. I have tested it and it works great — when you are doing something it is closing app and you must enter pin. Your Web application should turn in every minute and check if time has passed.

Comment: Nice solution, but it relies on Internet connection.

Comment: Use Local Notification instead of a Push Notification.

Comment: local and push notifications look and sound the same, so kid will click "ok" and it will closed